# Using Scala pattern matching to find whether a List contains a value

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

I've seen a range of different matches you can do against a List using pattern matching.  Is it possible to use pattern matching to identify if any (and ideally which) element in a list contains value x?  So something like this:

```
def contains(text: List[Char], chr: Char): Boolean = text match{
  case *pattern matching chr to any value in text* => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Just trying to learn what it can and can't do.

(I know I can use text.contains(chr), BTW)

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

What I have seen is use matching on list to recurse, in your case something like this probably:

```
def contains(text: List[Char], chr: Char): Boolean = text match{
  case head :: tail  => head.equals(chr) || contains(tail, chr)
  case Nil => false
}
```

I don't think you can use the match to do this kind of operations because of how the `unapply` method of list is defined, theoretically if you know the length of the list you could write something like

```
case x1 :: x2 :: x3 // and so on
```

But I guess you can see by yourself that this is not practical nor ideal for param-matching.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if that what you are looking for, but you can put `if` expressions in pattern matching.

this code looks artificial, but it demonstrates how to put `contains` or other random functions in pattern matching.

```
scala> def contains(text: List[Char], chr: Char): Boolean = text match{
     |     case _ if text.contains(chr) => true
     |     case _ => false
     | }
contains: (text: List[Char], chr: Char)Boolean

scala> contains(List('a', 'b', 'c'), 'd')
res2: Boolean = false

scala> contains(List('a', 'b', 'c'), 'c')
res3: Boolean = true
```